# Intel Media Server Studio on CentOS7.2

Tags: encoding, intel, decoding, intel-media-sdk

I am trying to install and configure ***Intel Media Server Studio*** on a ***CentOS7.2*** Machine with integrated VGA Graphics Card.

For validation of Successful installation([example](http://streambuilder.pro/docs/requirements/enabling-iqsv/)), *Metrics Monitor sample program* fails with error code 1.

```
Command:   ./_bin/metrics_monitor
```

> ERROR: Failed to subscribe for metrics, error code 1

Test programs are also getting crashed, below are the machine specification:-

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
           (Intel Quick-Sync supported)

Graphics: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller 
          (lspci | grep VGA)
```

I am following [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjRt8GO1ejPAhXIqY8KHZ7VDDcQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.intel.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fmedia_server_studio_getting_started_guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF3X_NQwhGbY6tW5zI9sttSOKtv6w&sig2=MeRSJ993Ix1v_CsK-slkuQ&bvm=bv.136499718,d.c2I&cad=rja) to install and configure. I have verified pre-requisite for this installation out of which below is **not** matching:

```
 vainfo | grep -v 'unknown'
```

Output on my machine:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.99.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_32
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

Can anybody tell what is wrong with the installation? as `metric_monitor` should give gpu usage.